# how to add floating number in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

```
a=-1.4
b=42273.85
awk "BEGIN {print ($a + $b)}"
```

42272.4

I am expecting result as **42272.45**, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a precision so awk picked one for you (`%.6g`, the default for `CONVFMT`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables):

```
a=-1.4
b=42273.85
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", (a + b)}'
42272.45
```

I'm also correcting your use of shell variables in an awk script above, see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Comment: thanks for your help, I have corrected my variables and m good to go. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to do floating point math in `sh`, `bash`, `zsh` and more is using `bc`

```
echo "$a + $b" | bc
42272.45
```

Using `awk` you can override the internal default output format by using `printf`

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{printf("%.2f\n", a + b)}' 
42272.45
```

Answer (score 0):

You might either use `printf` or set [`OFMT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html) variable, which will affect `print` as follows

```
a=-1.4
b=42273.85
awk -v a=$a -v b=$b 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.2f";print a + b}'
```

gives output

```
42272.45
```

Explanation: `OFMT` is supposed to be *floating-point conversion specification* which `print` uses when it encounters number, default is `%.6g`. Observe that `OFMT` is handy when you have multiple `print`s which are supposed to output numbers in uniform way.